# Need some help regarding an if-else piece of code

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have a piece of code I'm working with, that involves checking a condition and moving backwards to re-enter information if an invalid input is made. Please find the code, below:

```
Gender:
Console.WriteLine("Select Gender"
    +"\n (M)ale/(F)emale");
input = Console.ReadLine();

if (input=="M" || input==("m"))
    commonobj.gender = 1;

else if (input != ("F")||input!="f")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input, please enter again");
    goto Gender;
}
```

**Intended behaviour:**
If the user inputs 'M' or 'm', the value of the object variable is changed.
If the user inputs 'F' or 'f', the value of the object variable is unchanged.
If the user inputs any other value, an error statement should be displayed and the user asked to re-enter the information.

**Variables used:**
input - local variable, type String
| commonobj.gender - object variable

**Current behaviour:**
Entering 'F' or 'f' on the console displays the code under the 'else if' loop,

*What am I doing wrong?*

Note: The code executes as intended with 'm' being selected on the input.

Comment: `else if (input != ("F") && input!="f")` should be `&&`

Comment: So you are asking SO to solve your assignment?

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: @Saleem It is okay to ask for help as long as you have shown enough effort.

Comment: If you are not explicitly required using `if` for this task, using `switch` would be way easier.

Comment: side note: `goto` is *evil* in the context; change to *loop*, e.g. `while` one.

Comment: Alternatively you can compare with  `input.ToLower().Equals("m")`

Comment: @Nekeniehl - better to use `string.Equals(input, "m", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` //or a stringcomparision to your liking

Comment: This is actually a very well asked question

Comment: Thank you, Dmitry will try to implement that, and revert if I need any assistance. Cheers!

Comment: Tried a "do-while" loop, and it worked, Dmitry. Had to reinitialize 'error' variable at the beginning of the loop, though. Thank you so much, for the advice.

Comment: That worked, @Nekeniehl , thank you so much for the advice, your input helped optimize my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an and in your last conditional statement

```
Gender:
    Console.WriteLine("Select Gender"
        +"\n (M)ale/(F)emale");
    input = Console.ReadLine();

    if (input=="M" || input==("m")) {
        commonobj.gender = 1;

    } else if (input != ("F") && input!="f")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input, please enter again");
        goto Gender;
    }
```

Better to use

```
        if (input.Equals("M", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) { 
            commonobj.gender = 1;

        } else if (!input.Equals("F", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input, please enter again");
            goto Gender;
        }
```

Comment: Notice that this code never sets `commonobj.gender` if its female.

Comment: You are missing an }.

Comment: @RandRandom This is intended behavior according to the OP: *"If the user inputs 'F' or 'f', the value of the object variable is unchanged."*

Comment: @RandRandom "If the user inputs 'F' or 'f', the value of the object variable is unchanged"

Comment: Why did I get marked down for this answer? so badly?

Comment: @Filburt /BenMorris - never bothered to read that far :D

Comment: @BenMorris propably haters who downvote answers on their opinion low quality questions

Comment: Yes, bad question is fare but to answers???

Comment: Yes the variable is set to 0 by default @Rand Random. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the answer Ben, if @Dmitry Bychenko had made the comment, I'd have voted for his answer.